# The sprintf shows error. Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c++11

I think the argument types are wrong. Also can you check whether the sort function will work properly or not?? I have written this code to make the largest no possible by combining the integers in vector A.

```
string Solution::largestNumber(const vector<int> &A) {
    int  i,n;
    vector<string> B;
    string str;
    for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
    {
        n=sprintf(B[i],"%d",A[i]);
    }
    sort(A.begin(), A.end(),[](string lhs,  string rhs){
      //[](const string &lhs, const string &rhs) {
        // reverse the order of comparison to sort in descending order,
        // otherwise we'll get the "big" numbers at the end of the vector
        return rhs+lhs < lhs+rhs;
      });
      for(i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
      {
          str+= to_string(A[i]);
      }
      return str;
}
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include the actual error you are asking about.

Comment: `B[i]` is undefined behavior since `B` is empty.  You never use `B` anywhere else, so I'm not sure why that code is even there.  You used `to_string` at the bottom, why wouldn't you also use it at the top rather than `sprintf`?  Your sort makes no sense.  If `lhs` and `rhs` are different then the addition is meaningless since the compare would have already stopped, and if they are the same then the addition keeps them the same.

Answer (score 2):

B is a vector of std::string.

B[I] is then a std::string

sprintf expects an array of char, not a std::string.